# LINQ to Entities (.NET 4.0)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have the code below (this is actually part of a much more complicated query, but I have isolated the issue to this particular line to help with debugging) which per everything I have read should create an IN clause in SQL, assuming I am using EF4. As far as I can tell, I am using EF4 (We are using .NET Framework 4 for our projects and when I look at the System.Data and System.Data.Entity they both say version 4.0.0.0 for all the projects)

```
int[] assessmentIDs; // this is just here to show what this is, 
                     // but it is a params parameter passed to this methed                  

var assessments = from cert in container.ProctorAssessmentCertifications
                  where assessmentIDs.Contains(cert.AssessmentID)
                  select cert.ID;
```

However, when I run this, I get the runtime error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int32](Int32[], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

When I use LinqPad, it does correctly output an IN clause like one would expect in EF4. 
My questions are:

A. What am I doing wrong and how do I make this work?

B. How do I force EF4 to be called if in fact it's not? I can find no reference in any web.config file that point it to the older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contains does not get translated into valid SQL because assessmentIDs is not IQueryable, it is an in-memory object. So you'll have to pull the data out first, and then do the check.

```
var assessments = (from cert in container.ProctorAssessmentCertifications                  
                  select cert.ID).ToList() //no longer IQueryable.

var result = assessments.Intersect(assessmentIDs);
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants as this retrieves all the data from the server. The OP wants the 'Intersect' to be done by SQL Server for obvious performances considerations.

Comment: @ken2k What if this is only a lookup table and the performance implications are minimal? Why don't you post the solution?

Comment: That would logically be a tad slow. I solved it by doing the inverse though:  
    IQueryable<int> ids = assessmentIDs.AsQueryable(); and then using ids instead of assessmentIDs in the above query.